# How to randomly draw Quaternions within a specific range of Euler angles for rotation?

Tags: python, math, graphics, 3d, quaternions

I am pretty new to Quaternions so please bear with me. I want to draw random Quaternion samples so that their Euler angle equivalent would range within `[-30, +30]` degrees on each axis. Currently, I know how to sample Quaternions from the full range (`[-180, +180]`) using the code below but I don't know how to modify the code so that I can get samples within the range `[-30, +30]`. Can anyone help me with that?

I'm not sure if this is helpful to answer this question but here's a piece of information: I eventually want to convert the sampled Quaternion to Euler angles an apply the Euler rotation in some 3D shapes. The order of rotation in the software I'm using to do this is `XYZ` meaning that it first rotates the 3D shape along the `X` axis, then `Y` axis and then `Z` axis.

```
import numpy as np
def sample_Quaternion():
    r = np.random.uniform(0, 1 - 0.001, 3)
    while np.linalg.norm(r) > 1:
        r = np.random.uniform(0, 1 - 0.001, 3) # Just to keep the L2 norm within [0, 1.0)
    w = [np.sqrt(1 - (r[0]*r[0] + r[1]*r[1] + r[2]*r[2]))]
    r = np.concatenate(r, w) # the output of this would represent (x, y, z, w)
    return r
```

Comment: Also [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2973849/35416) on Math SE. Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/188688). Since the question is more about mathematics than programming, I suggest closing this here and waiting for results from the Math post.

Comment: If you have your constraints in Euler angle representation, and you want to convert to Euler angles, I do not see any reason to sample in Quaternion space. Why not sample Euler angles directly?